# How to Generate Format file without doing BCP out operation in SYBASE explicitly

Tags: sybase, bcp

I am searching for a utility , which can help me generate Format file for any a table without doing BCP out in Sybase.

I understand and know about the solution for generating Format file by Invoking BCP out operation. but downside of this approach is  as follows 
1. It is completely manual and given a scenario where I have to do for  1600 tables with huge number of columns , it will be a nightmare . 
2. if DDL of any  table will change , then keeping track and regenerating will be a pain.

If any one can advice/suggest me  a solution , with which  I could achieve both or either one of the requirement , then it will ease my work.

Thanks 
Andy

Comment: Do you absolutely require format files?  Normally it's straightforward to use "-c", and you can change the field separator to a character or string not present in the data if necessary.

Comment: "-c" option is slower when its comes to handling tables with  250 M  of Data. BCP has a Native format option which is much faster and clubbing it with format file option gives me the control of selecting what needs to be pushed in or out.  I am working on a Data Migration Assignment and revamping the Architecture of a Live environment where I cant take chances.

Comment: I see.  Well - I guess I'd use perl  to read syscolumns and systypes to generate the format files.  I can see that might be a chore but I reckon it would work ok.  You might have user types, which would complicate things a little, but in principle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automate this by using xp_cmdshell to kick off a BCP-out to generate a format file. You can call xp_cmdshell from a stored procedure so you can execute it for every table in the catalogs.
But as mentioned here too, do you really need all those format files?